# Best way to optimize this SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have to optimize this query and I am really in a hurry here. The following query searches by client. The input value `RIF.keyvaluechar 
LIKE 'V%10553790 '` is because in some old registers in the database some IDs when missing characters it used to be V0012345678 but it should have been V12345678 as that's the maximum amount of characters the ID can have. I know 12345678 should have been numeric and the V a char and then compare, but that's another issue.

Anyway, the query is this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT idata.itemnum AS [ID], 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(CONTRATO.keyvaluechar,'N/A'))) AS [Contrato],
                idata.datestored AS [Fecha], 
                NUMERO.keyvaluesmall AS [Numero], 
                TIPO.keyvaluechar AS [Tipo], 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(LC.lifecyclename,'N/A'))) AS [Flujo], 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(LC.lcnum,-1))) AS [FlujoID], 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(LCS.statename,'N/A'))) AS [Cola], 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(LCS.statenum,-1))) AS [ColaID], 
                CASE 
                    WHEN PC.NombreProceso IN('PTD','PV2','PV3') THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END AS [Portada] 
FROM OnBase.hsi.itemdata idata WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN OnBase.hsi.keyitem109 TIPO WITH (NOLOCK) ON TIPO.itemnum = idata.itemnum 
    INNER JOIN OnBase.hsi.keyitem113 NUMERO WITH (NOLOCK) ON NUMERO.itemnum = idata.itemnum 
    LEFT JOIN OnBase.hsi.keyitem132 CONTRATO WITH (NOLOCK) ON CONTRATO.itemnum = idata.itemnum 
    LEFT JOIN OnBase.hsi.keyitem114 CLIENTE WITH (NOLOCK) ON CLIENTE.itemnum = idata.itemnum 
    LEFT JOIN OnBase.hsi.keyitem111 RIF WITH (NOLOCK) ON RIF.itemnum = idata.itemnum 
    INNER JOIN OnBase.hsi.doctype DOC WITH (NOLOCK) ON DOC.itemtypenum = idata.itemtypenum 
    INNER JOIN BD_WorkFlow.dbo.BBVA_ProcesosConfig PC WITH (NOLOCK) ON PC.ID_Documento = idata.itemtypenum 
    LEFT JOIN Onbase.hsi.itemlc ILC WITH (NOLOCK) ON ILC.itemnum = idata.itemnum 
    LEFT JOIN Onbase.hsi.lcstate LCS WITH (NOLOCK) ON LCS.statenum = ILC.statenum 
    LEFT JOIN Onbase.hsi.lifecycle LC WITH (NOLOCK) ON LC.lcnum = ILC.lcnum 
WHERE PC.NombreProceso <> 'XXX' AND 
      PC.NombreProceso NOT IN('PTD','PV2','PV3') AND 
      TIPO.keyvaluechar = 'CCD' AND 
      RIF.keyvaluechar LIKE 'V%10553790 '
```

As you can see it is this way so it finds V0012345678 or V12345678 but this is not the right way or I feel it is the best optimization, although I am no expert in databases.

Anyways, I've though about something like this instead of last line

```
AND LEFT ('RIF.Keyvaluechar, 1) ="V"
AND SUBSTRING (RIF.Keyvaluechar, 2, LEN(RIF.Keyvaluechar)) = "12345678"
```

What do you guys think? Is there any other better way to improve upon this?

Comment: You do a Left Join on RIF, only to filter it down later with the where clause.  Why not add that criteria to the Join and make it an Inner join?

Comment: It seems like you aren't really using `CLIENTE` except for checking if it exists. Review that table to see if you really need it and if you do then you can check if `itemnum` exists in that table by using an inner join instead or an `EXISTS` check. Also what sort of indexes do you have on `OnBase.hsi.itemdata`? Indexes could help in optimizing queries.

Comment: Why do you check if PC.NombreProceso is  IN ('PTD','PV2','PV3') when they are excluded in the where clause? And why don't you put 'xxx' in the NOT IN condition?

Comment: As a side note you might take a peek at this article before you litter your database with NOLOCK hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2):

First, your query has a logic problem.  You have this:

```
LEFT JOIN OnBase.hsi.keyitem111 RIF WITH(NOLOCK) ON RIF.itemnum = idata.itemnum
```

and then this in your `where` clause:

```
AND RIF.keyvaluechar LIKE 'V%10553790 '
```

Putting that filter in your `where` clause effectively changes your left join to an inner join.  To fix this, move the filter to the join.

In terms of optimizing it, I assume that means to make it run faster. What you were thinking about will probably slow things down because you are filtering on function results instead of fields.  A better approach, no matter how much of a hurry you are in, is to look at the indexes in your database and try to filter on those.  In fact, it might be appropriate to add new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Keyvaluechar always a number from the second character onwards and you want to treat it as a number (=remove leading zeros). You could try to add a persisted column `convert(int, SUBSTRING (Keyvaluechar, 2, 10))` to the table, then index that, and use it as a search criteria. At least I would assume that should help a lot.

In addition to that, looking at statistics IO output might be a good idea too, to see what table is actually responsible for the biggest I/O amounts.

Just a note, I hope you also know the problems using NOLOCK can cause you.

Comment: I didnt do this code, or the query, i am just triying to optimize it. The option i gave above reduces time from 59 seconds to 7, BUT it is not returning the code i want because it is removing the 00 when there is, but when there isnt, it is removing it. I will try with some conditional

Comment: @Swimcito Sorry can't really understand what you're trying to say, but if the problem is that you need just to compare the end of the string, you could do a computed column with reverse, and then also reverse your search string, and use like '87654321%' -- I know that's ugly, but it might work ;)